# Copying a virtual machine data drive in Microsoft Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

Added more details at the bottom of the question.

We are testing deployment scenarios in Azure VM preview and have run into an issue.

Here is our scenario.  We have a software stack that we use in all of our servers.  We have created an image with all of that stack installed on an attached data drive. We have created a image of the VM that we can use as a template.   Now what we want to do is to to create a VM based on  that template  and create a copy of the data drive and attach it to the newly created VM in an automated manner.

Our problem is that while we have found lots of information about creating drives, we can't find any guidance on how to copy the data drive using Azure for Powershell.

Any thoughts, code, or RTFMs happily accepted.

Cheers,

Terence

We have sucessfully created an operating system image that we can use to create VM's.  But there is a data disk that holds our standard software stack that we want to reuse by copying it across VMs.  The scenario that we are trying to implement is:

1. Create a VM from a standard VM image - PBIMaster
2. Attach a disk as F to that image called PBIMasterDisk
3. Install all of the software required for our app on F: (to big for the OS disk and besides sticking it on the OS disk seems messy)
4. Build an image from PBIMaster call it PBIMasterImage save it.
5. Create a new image from PBIMaster call it Node1
6. Copy PBIMasterDisk to a new Azure disk call it Node1Software disk
7. Attach Node1Softwaredisk to Node1 as F:

Since the image has the correct registry settings from the previous installs our stack is ready to go.

9 Add appropriate endpoints.

Rinse and repeat for each additional node.

Hopefully that makes our scenario clearer.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on feedback I have entered a more detailed description below the orginial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your objective correctly you already have uploaded two VHD in your subscription and you have also create a VM based on your OS Disk VHD1:

1. OS Disk (VHD1)
2. Data Disk (VHD2)

Now you want to copy VHD2 to VHD3 and then attach VHD3 to your VM (which is based on OS disk) via Powershell.

As of there is no powershell command which will let you copy DataDisk (VHD2)  to another data disk (i.e VHD3)..

I haven't tried but you can use the following code to try copying your DataDisk:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx

This method does copy blobs directly at cloud storage level so there is no bandwidth usage towards on-premise and potentially zero cost if you are in same DC. Trying using the same subscription and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.. working on it and will get back soon with exact info.

Comment: Marked as answer - I was hoping to avoid using anything but powershell but I don't think its possible at this point.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: As this whole things is still in preview mode however I hope such functionality soon will be available through PS as well.. Thanks!!